# Way to parallelize QCA minimize() in R?

Tags: r, loops, parallel-processing, nested-loops

I'm using the R package QCA (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/QCA/index.html) for *Qualitative Comparative Analysis*. I want to be able to try out many different combinations, which is taking a very long time. On my faster CPU, trying all the options that I am interested in takes a little over 24 hours. R seems to be using only one of the cores available on my CPU and requires relatively little memory (just under 100MB). I am hoping someone has a good idea on how to speed up this process, perhaps through parallelization?

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Loading my data set (*data*), which is a CSV file with the outcome condition and all the options for my causal conditions. The causal conditions are in 4 groups A, B, C, and D. There are approx. 200 observations, i.e., rows in the data set.
2. Starting a log file with sink()
3. Creating a series of nested loops to generate each combination of causal conditions I want to examine.
4. Running the minimize() function within the nested loops. Specifically this looks like this:

```
for (a in causal_condition_group_A) {
    for (b in causal_condition_group_B) {
        for (c in causal_condition_group_C) {
            for (d in causal_condition_group_D) {
                minimize(data, outcome = my_outcome, conditions = paste0(a, ", ", b, ", ",  c, ", ",  d), ...)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The minimize function's *conditions* argument essentially takes a character vector as input and this is all my nested loops are creating. For example, a random conditions argument might read:

`conditions = "causal_condition_A_87, causal_condition_B_2, causal_condition_C_42, causal_condition_D_219"`

I tried several different things in an attempt to parallelize this approach, but so far I have not been successful. I tried experimenting with both parSapply and foreach %dopar%, but I am running into various problems. I either can't get the actual parallelization process to work properly or - and this is in some of my toy experiments - I am having trouble logging all the output, which is essential.

Please let me know if I can provide additional information to help clear things up! Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

I was able to create a working `foreach()` loop based on @HenrikB's advice, but I'm running into a different problem now.

Here's my *test* solution so far. It includes one less nested loop than I want in the final solution, but that's not important for now:

```
# SET QCA OUTCOME CONDITION
outcome = "c_outcome"

# LOAD LIBRARIES
library(doParallel)
library(QCA)

# CREATE CLUSTER FOR PARALLELIZATION
cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1, type = "PSOCK", outfile="")
registerDoParallel(cl)

# LOAD AND SET UP DATA
outcomecond <- read.csv("outcomes.csv", header=TRUE, row.names="ID")
causalcond <- read.csv("causal_conditions.csv", header=TRUE, row.names="ID")
data <- cbind(outcomecond[outcome], causalcond)
temp <- data[!is.na(data[outcome]), ] #keep only rows where outcome is not NA

# EXPORT CURRENT DATASET TO CLUSTERS
clusterExport(cl, "temp")

# CREATE CAUSAL CONDITION LISTS
causal_condition_group_A <- colnames(causalcond[, 1:99])
causal_condition_group_B <- colnames(causalcond[, 100:141])
causal_condition_group_C <- colnames(causalcond[, 142:183])

# EXPORT LIBRARIES TO CLUSTERS
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(doParallel))
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(QCA))

# START TIMER
start.time <- Sys.time()

# THREE NESTED FOREACH LOOPS (ONE FOR EACH CAUSAL CONDITION GROUP)
x <-
  foreach(c=causal_condition_group_C, .combine='cbind') %:%
    foreach(b=causal_condition_group_B, .combine='cbind') %:%
      foreach(a=causal_condition_group_A, .combine='cbind') %dopar% {
        tryCatch({
          minimize(temp, outcome = outcome, conditions = paste0(a,",",b,",",c), n.cut = 1, incl.cut = 0.400, include = "?", details = TRUE, use.letters = TRUE)
        }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
  }

# END TIMER
end.time <- Sys.time()

# PROGRAM RUNNING TIME:
print(end.time - start.time)

# END CLUSTER
stopCluster(cl)
```

When I run this as a sequential `%do%` loop, I need something like 3 GB of memory to store `x`. However, when I try to run this sequentially, the memory rises exponentially. Here's a screenshot from shortly before I gave up:

[Screenshot of task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FxkO.png)

Does someone know why `%dopar%` is using so much more memory and is there a way to avoid this?

Could I, for example, be writing `x` to file once in a while and purge memory after I do this? `x` is a list that is of dimension 14 by number of iterations in the `foreach()` loops. Here is what one of the "columns" in `x` looks like:

```
           result.98
tt         List,11
options    List,10
negatives  Numeric,3
initials   "~A*B"
PIchart    TRUE
primes     Integer,2
solution   List,1
essential  "~A*B"
inputcases "205,245,253,306,425,468,490,511,514,585,587,657,684,696,739,740,784,796"
pims       List,1
IC         List,4
numbers    Numeric,4
SA         List,1
call       Expression
```

Comment: The value of `minimize(...)` is not assigned to anything. Is that a mistake?

Comment: @HenrikB The output is currently being sent to my log file. I then use that to further evaluate the results. I'm open to doing this differently, but it's fine too if the solution just keeps printing the results.

Comment: I see. You can't reliably have multiple workers write to the same file in parallel; their output will be interweaved and nothing make sense.  If you need to write to file, then each call needs to be written to a separate file.  Afterward you can merge them into a single file.  However, unless data is huge, it's probably better to return values and you handle them in R

Comment: For parallelization: the foreach package provides the `%:%` operator which allows you "flatten" nested `foreach()` calls.  But I suggest that you start focusing on parallelizing your inner for-loop first and get that working.  Then you can worry about the outer ones later.

Comment: I am able to get ```foreach()``` to work, but only as long as I am not trying to run it in parallel. Whenever I switch to running in parallel, the variable where I saved the output from the loop only returns ```NULL```. The strange thing is, it does work fine when I am running one of the example loops in the nested loops vignette (http://127.0.0.1:29618/library/foreach/doc/nested.html) - which is very similar to my test loop: ```x <-  foreach(b=group_B, .combine='cbind') %:% foreach(a=group_A, .combine='cbind') %dopar% { minimize(..., paste(a, ",", b), ...) }```